# InputStream - At what point is data downloaded

Tags: java, stream

I have 4 lines of code to download an Bitmap,

```
URL u = new URL(webaddress);

InputStream in = null;

in = u.openStream();

icon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
```

I'm planning on changing the last line to do something similar to this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) where I only load into memory an image of set size to reduce memory usage. However i don't want this to involve another server call/download so I'm curious which of the four lines above actually downloads the data from the source?

Im going to be changing the last line of code to the last two functions in the tutorial mentioned above so could do with knowing if its going to mean downloading more or less data, (I'm trying to only download a small image from one that could be for example 5 megapixels)

Apologies if this is simple / the wrong way to think about it im not very experienced with data streams.

---

**EDIT**

im using these two functions to replace the last line of code above:
calling:

```
image = decodeSampledBitmapFromStram(in, 300,300);
```

Image quality is not a priority, will this mean more data downloaded?

```
private static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
            int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and
            // width
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height
                    / (float) reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

            // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will
            // guarantee
            // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
            // requested height and width.
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }

    private Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromStream(InputStream in, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        Rect padding = new Rect();
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, padding, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
                reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, padding, options);
    }
```

Comment: You could read the inputstream into a buffer, then make an inputstream from the buffer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last of your four lines is responsible for the entire download.  `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);` is going to continue pulling data from that stream until either the entire image has been downloaded or an error occurs midway through.

As for the bandwidth issue, I'd be very careful to understand exactly how the decoder downsamples large images before trying things out.  In reducing a large image to a smaller size, the only way to do this in a high-quality manner is to downsample by averaging pixels in the original image. If the decoder does downsample in this manner, then you won't save any bandwidth, because the decoder will still need to read every pixel of the original image, even if not every pixel gets stored in RAM.  You can downsample more quickly by not reading every pixel in the original image, at the cost of final image quality.  Along those lines, I did notice an option for preferring "Quality over Speed":

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inPreferQualityOverSpeed

I have a feeling that, for this particular option, you gain more speed by reading less data, but the API states this only works for JPEGs.  Not sure if that helps your particular use case, but it might be worth looking into.

Comment: So based on the assumption that i prefer speed and reduced data downloaded over quality, would you suggest i stick with code line four or swap it with the two functions?

Comment: If "prefer speed" works the way I think it does then it will reduce the amount of data read, therefore decreasing bandwidth required.  If it doesn't work that way, then there will be no bandwidth difference and you're better off keeping your original code. If all else fails, just try them both and see if you can determine which version reads more data.  Is there any way to use an `InputStream` in the `decodeResource` version of the method call?  If so, you could use that to determine exactly how many bytes were read (e.g. downloaded).

Comment: how would i use an InputStream to measure how many bytes are read? I could probably modify both codes to have access to the InputStream

Comment: You could extend `InputStream` and have it wrap whatever `InputStream` you're currently using - just pass all `InputStream` methods through from your implementation to the wrapped stream instance.  Then, in your implementation of the `read()` method, increment a counter every time that method gets called successfully - this will give you the number of bytes read over the duration of each `decode[Stream/Resource]()` call.

Answer (score 1):

The following document would help you better understand about streaming http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/streams.html. In short, once a connection to the resource location is established, a definite sized buffer (portion of data) is retrieved/read. Typically, this process is continued until all of the portions are read.

The main advantage of streaming is to operate in a piece meal fashion. For example, say if you want to download an image that is 500 MB in size. Rather than transferring this in one shot, streaming allows to download in chunks. This is better in error handling, retries, peak network utilization etc.